# Weird inventory in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm new to minecraft java edition please tell me why does not all items are showing in the inventory, I played Minecraft UWP Edition where I got all items, but with Minecraft Launcher it is wired.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in Survival Mode. If you want something you will have to find/craft it.

If you want instant access to everything, you'll want to be in Creative Mode.

This applies to both versions of Minecraft.

---

> How do I switch Gamemodes?

## Java, without recreating

1. Pause your game.
2. "Open to LAN"
3. In the settings, enable cheats.
4. Actually click the button that opens to LAN.
5. Type `/gamemode creative`.

## Java, with recreating

1. When you create your world, select "Gamemode: Survival" and click until it shows "Gamemode: Creative".
2. Click on "More Options"
3. Ensure "Enable Cheats: On" is showing. If it is "Off", click the button to turn it on.

## Bedrock

1. Go to Pause Menu
2. Go to World Settings
3. Enable Cheats
4. Say 'yes' to forfeiting the ability to earn any achievements
5. Turn on Creative in the same menu or open chat and type `/gamemode creative`.

Answer (score 0):

You are in survival mode. In survival mode you have to gather resources. If you want everything at the start, switch to creative mode.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the arquade. have you seen the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)? This answer is not essentially any different from the accepted answer, it contains no new information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers that don't add any new information over an existing much older accepted answer. Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/how-should-we-deal-with-duplicate-answers.